# What is an elegant Ruby way to have a condition of 'nil'?

Tags: ruby, hash, block

Is there a more elegant way to write this code?

```
    def create_a_hash_from_a_collection
      my_hash = {}

      collection_of_hashes.each do |key, value|
        my_hash[key] = {} if my_hash[key].nil?
        my_hash[key] = value
      end

      my_hash
    end
```

The line that seems clumsy to me is this:

`my_hash[key] = {} if my_hash[key].nil?`

Is there a shorthand way of expressing it?

Comment: Why would you need this anyway if you assigning `value` on next line?

Comment: Are we to assume a "collection" here is an array of hashes? Where will this data be provided from?

Comment: can you please add output of `collection_of_hashes` variable? is it array of hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `||=` operator which does exactly what you want

```
my_hash[key] ||= {}
```

The rest of my answer here is because I'm not sure what a "collection of hashes" is, so my best guess is that it would be an array of hashes.  If I'm wrong, let me know and disregard the rest of this answer.

It seems that the rest of your method may not do what it sounds like you're trying to do.  Consider:

```
@collection_of_hashes = [{foo: 'bar'}, {baz: 'qux'}]

def create_a_hash_from_a_collection
   my_hash = {}
   @collection_of_hashes.each do |key, value|
     # this is not actually doing anything here and returns same with or
     # without the following line
     # my_hash[key] ||= {}
     my_hash[key] = value
   end

   my_hash
 end
#=> {{:foo=>"bar"}=>nil, {:baz=>"qux"}=>nil}
```

But what you probably want is

```
def create_a_hash_from_a_collection
  my_hash = {}
  @collection_of_hashes.each do |hash|
    hash.keys.each do |k|
      my_hash[k] = hash[k]
    end
  end
  my_hash
end
#=> {:foo=>"bar", :baz=>"qux"}
```

But also keep in mind, if any of your "collection of hashes" which we would tend to assume would be an array of hashes, contain the same key, which one wins? This code, it would be the last item in the array's key value. What is the actual goal of your method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a brand new hash for each key in your initial hash you need to initialise it with a block:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }

hash[:foo].object_id == hash[:bar].object_id #=> false
```

Otherwise, if you do this, It will be always the same default hash

```
hash = Hash.new({})
hash[:foo].object_id == hash[:bar].object_id #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is to initialise your `my_hash` with a default value, so then you don't need to check if it's nil or not.

That can be done using the `Hash.new` constructor, compare:

```
my_hash = {}
puts my_hash['no_existing_key'] #=> nil

my_hash = Hash.new({})
puts my_hash['no_existing_key'] #=> {}
```

You then can reduce your code to:

```
def create_a_hash_from_a_collection
  my_hash = Hash.new({})

  collection_of_hashes.each do |key, value|
    my_hash[key] = value
  end

  my_hash
end
```

Comment: Although as mentioned by Interdictor in his answer. This default `Hash` is a single reference so `my_hash['no_existing_key'].merge!({name: 'Nope'})` means that `my_hash['another_no_existing_key'] #=> {name: 'Nope'}` because this default value in this case is acting almost like an accumulator and `my_hash['no_existing_key']` still not have a actual value and `my_hash.key?('no_existing_key') #=> false`. Where as the original implementation is akin to `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }` where each non existing key gets its own new `Hash` and becomes part of the original `Hash`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning value anyway, maybe you could use `my_hash[key] = value || {}`?

So, if `value` to assign is `nil`, the value of that key becomes `{}`.

Comment: This seems like the most logical solution however it has a different result than the current code

Comment: @engineersmnky is it actually clear what the OP is trying to achieve?

Comment: Not at all. Thus no answer from me :)